# In-vivo racemization of thalidomide

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

In 1961, thalidomide was first introduced as an over-the-counter cure for morning sickness. Pregnant women across the country began to take the drug, which worked well, but shortly after, babies began to be born with severe birth defects. Experts linked this to thalidomide and later discovered that the r-enantiomer, which was the cure for morning sickness, underwent a certain reaction (or reactions) within the body that could change its configuration to that of the s-enantiomer. Does anyone know the steps of this reaction or at least what it is called?
[image]

Comment: The stereocentre has an acidic proton attached (the H). This can undergo enolisation (due to the presence of the carbonyl). As the enolate form is planar (and hence chiral), the stereochemical information is lost (there is no chiral memory). When the enolate re-converts to the carbonyl form, it does so to form a racemic mixture. The process is usually called epimirisation and is common to all stereocentres directly adjacent to a carbonyl (under the right conditions, some are more prone to epimirisation than others-  in this case the epimirisation happens in vivo).

Comment: With all that text at the beginning, this sounds like a homework assignment with only the last sentence fixed :D